# 3d ternary scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, ternary, dirichlet

I would like to be able to create a plot of four variables that are compositions. The fourth variable is simply 1.0 minus the first three.

```
library(DirichletReg)

#remove(list=ls())

set.seed(1)
A<-runif(100,0,0.25)
B<-runif(100,0,0.25)
C<-runif(100,0,0.25)
D<-(1.0-(A+B+C))
POINT<-c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20))
df<-data.frame(cbind(A,B,C,D,POINT))
```

I can produce some good quality plots of three variables, but some adjustments take place to ensure that the subcomposition sums to 1.0. This is not ideal and distorts the data. Also I'd like to customise the colours given to each axis.

```
AL<-DR_data(df[, c("A","B","C")])
plot(AL, 
    dim.labels = c("Compound A","Compound B","Compound C"),
    pch = df$POINT,
    col = df$POINT)
```

But by simply providing the full list I can generate an interactive plot but it is missing desireable elements:

1) The symbols are all the same colour and shape
2) there are no axis grids (but these may be confusing in a 3d plot?)
3) there are no axis labels

```
AL<-DR_data(df[, c("A","B","C","D")])
plot(AL, 
     dim.labels = c("Compound A","Compound B","Compound C","Compound D"),
     pch = df$POINT,
     col = df$POINT)
```

Does anyone know of an alternative function that produces a 3d (using 4 variables) that is more akin to the 2d (using 3 variables) plot? Thanks.

EDIT : I am not really qualified to adopt a package. )o: Does anyone know of an alternative package / software to achieve something close to my desire? The CoDaPack software comes close but isn't very configurable. http://ima.udg.edu/codapack/

[image: 3D Ternary plot produced by CoDA]

Comment: That's a bug in the `plot.DirichletRegData` function.  It never passes the `pch` argument to `rgl::points3d`.  Unfortunately, `DirichletReg` has no maintainer (it is listed as "ORPHANED"), so you'll need to take over as maintainer or find someone else to do that if you want it fixed.